# How can i fit different background images of different sizes to take same width when using background size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to loop a set of images in a loop each image has different dimentions, if i give bgsize as 30px some images look bigger and some smaller

```
      <div style={{ background:`url(${image}) no-repeat center`,backgroundSize:'40px' }}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided more code context on what other styles these divs have, because by default empty divs won't have any size.

But presuming each div in the list has a fixed width and height, I imagine the issue is the different images have different *aspect ratios*, which will mean wider images look smaller in the divs, as in the below example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.bg {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 80px;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg" style="background-image: url('https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1l4T6MDQgqo/WSKvmmZ-KJI/AAAAAAAAAyM/xD2vAPs6JF8pLJl6lhnceuRdKWntNYovACLcB/s1600/9.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="bg" style="background-image: url('https://worldoffloweringplants.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Gaillardia-Blanket-Flowers.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="bg" style="background-image: url('https://jeffreyfavero.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/JFP-WYO-105.jpg');"></div>
</div>
```

There are at least two ways to make this look better, depending on the context of your scenario.

1. Providing two values to `background-size` fixes both the width *and* height of the image; by only setting one value, you are setting the width while allowing the height to automatically scale. In my example where the divs are of fixed size, this results in wonky image scaling that perhaps isn't ideal.
2. Providing the value of `cover` to `background-size` tells the browser to resize the image until it at least fills its container, cropping out extra bits if necessary. The result in my example is a series of square images that look the same size.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.bg2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg2" style="background-image: url('https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1l4T6MDQgqo/WSKvmmZ-KJI/AAAAAAAAAyM/xD2vAPs6JF8pLJl6lhnceuRdKWntNYovACLcB/s1600/9.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="bg2" style="background-image: url('https://worldoffloweringplants.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Gaillardia-Blanket-Flowers.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="bg2" style="background-image: url('https://jeffreyfavero.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/JFP-WYO-105.jpg');"></div>
</div>
```